Chrome displays text incorrectly despite correct page source
My Chrome browser recently started rendering some text incomprehensibly. After some digging it appears that this happens with certain basic fonts, such as Times. In other apps such as Pages, text in the Times font renders correctly. In this screenshot you can see that Chrome is not rendering text in Times font correctly:

How do I get Chrome to handle Times (or other fonts) correctly when it gets like this?
System:
Mac OS 14.2.1
Chrome 124.0.6367.156 (Official Build) (arm64)

So I would say maybe start by clearing the browser cache and resetting Chrome settings. If that doesn’t work try resetting Chrome settings by going to Chrome settings > Advanced > Reset settings, and clicking "Restore settings to their original defaults." Confirm the action and restart Chrome. Also, you could try disabling the hardware acceleration in Chrome settings > Advanced > System that might help.
Alternatively, make sure chrome is updated and check if the Times font is correctly installed on your macOS system. If the issue continues, maybe try using a different browser temporarily.
Hope that helps :)

Thanks, but none of these solved the issue

Have you tried reinstalling?

If you have, maybe try clearing the font cache on your Mac might help. You can do this by opening the "Font Book" application, selecting "File" >
"Restore Standard Fonts," and then restarting your computer.

I'm hoping to find a more targeted solution since this is a more isolated problem

Also @Michael I don't see "Restore Standard Fonts" under the File menu in Font Book, did you mean something else? And is there a reason you suspect this will solve the problem even though the font renders correctly in other apps?
